# Python - problems with shared variable

Tags: python

I'd like to use a shared queue from multiple threads and modules. I have the following Python code:

```
# moda.py

import queue
import modb

q = queue.Queue()

def myPut(x):
    q.put(x)

def main():
    print('moda:', str(id(q)))
    modb.go()
    q.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and

```
# modb.py

import moda
import threading


def something():
    print('modb:', str(id(moda.q)))
    moda.myPut('hi')


def go():
    threading.Thread(target = something).start()
```

`something` gets called on thread 1, `somethingElse` gets called on thread 2. The addresses of `q` are different in these two methods - which is why the call to `get` never returns. How can I avoid this? Is it because of the cyclic import or because of multithreading?

Comment: Cyclic imports are a bad idea in any case, and you don't seem to know the `import modb` in `moda`.

Comment: `import` will prevent cyclic imports (by not importing something it already has), but mutual imports are sure to confuse the reader (i.e. you and me)

Comment: @larsmans I need that import though. The modules communicate with each other.

Comment: Could you expand this to a runnable example?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/744403/302243) link for some nice info about circular imports.  Specifically this info may be important `That is the reason why cyclic imports may return modules which appear to be partly empty.`  You're better off having shared functionality in a third module.

Comment: @ryyst If you want modules to communicate, create a third module, import both and connect them together there. Circular dependencies are bad mkay.

Answer (score 3):

[The link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744403/222914) posted by Austin Phillips in the comments has the answer:

> Finally, the executing script runs in a module named __main__,
>   importing the script under its own name will create a new module
>   unrelated to __main__.

So, `__main__.q` and `moda.q` (as imported into `modb`) are two different objects.

One way to make it work is to create a separate main module like this and run it instead of `moda`:

```
# modmain.py

import moda

if __name__ == '__main__':
    moda.main()
```

However, you should still consider putting `q` and other shared stuff into a new module that you import into both `moda` and `modb` to avoid some other pitfalls.